# Undefined reference to operator!= when using std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I've been using a group of templated function `contains`

the code is as follows:

```
template<class V>
bool contains(const std::unordered_set<V>& c, const V& e)
{
    return c.find(e) != c.cend();
}
```

I also have similar version for std::set, std::map and std::unordered_map

However, I recently got linking errors when using it:

```
CMakeFiles/dietAgent.dir/agent/workflow/autoscale/AutoscaleCoreScheduler
.cc.o : Dans la fonction « bool contains<WfNode*, WfNode*>
(std::unordered_set<WfNode*, std::hash<WfNode*>, std::equal_to<WfNode*>, 
std::allocator<WfNode*> > const&, WfNode* const&) » :
    /home/amxx/Work/Thesis/Code/diet/src/utils/stdext.hh:51 : référence 
indéfinie vers « std::integral_constant<bool, true> operator!=
<std::__detail::_Node_const_iterator<WfNode*, true, false>, 
std::__detail::_Node_const_iterator<WfNode*, true, false> >
(std::__detail::_Node_const_iterator<WfNode*, true, false> const&, 
std::__detail::_Node_const_iterator<WfNode*, true, false> const&) »
```

what I understand from the error is that there is no `operator!=` for the iterators ... WTF ?

**Update:**

Apparently the templated wrapper is not to blame. I tryed using

```
if (mySet.find(value) != mySet.end()) { ... }
```

Directly (rather then calling `contains`) and I got the same `undefined referennce to operator!=`

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @wally, I tried but did not succeed... probably because the issue is at linkage ...

Comment: Do the `WfNode` objects change over time, or are they immutable?  May be irrelevant if it is the address that is the "value" in the set.

Comment: `WfNode` are not const, and they contain non-const methods, but the pointers should not be affected

Comment: changing `cend` to `end` would compare `std::__detail::_Node_const_iterator` and `std::__detail::_Node_iterator`, which doesn't solve anything and adds a unnecessary discrepancy

Comment: Worked for me.  What is the name of the header file that has your group of templated functions?

Comment: `stdext.hh` ... it used to work for me for weeks, and most of the calls are ok, but this afternoon it stopped working for some datastructures

Answer (score -1):

In your class you need to overload the operator **!=**.

Or you can use the operator **==** like in the following example:

```
template<class V>
bool contains(const std::unordered_set<V>& c, const V& e)
{
    return !(c.find(e) == c.cend());
}
```

Comment: I tried doing `!( == )` but it doesn't sove the issue.
Also my containers contains POINTERS to a class, so I shouldn't need to implement those operators in my class as they are not required to comparing pointers.

Once again, if you look at the error I am getting the objects that canoot be compared are `std::__detail::_Node_const_iterator<WfNode*, true, false>`